# Flickr image caching with Python

Tags: python, caching, flickr

My web application displays photos from a Flickr set. I'm using a [Python Flickr API](http://www.stuvel.eu/flickrapi) to gather information about my photos. I can cache the Flickr API call easily; however, I'm not sure what the best approach would be to cache the **images** locally as well. Is there an existing solution for this, or do I need to build my own?

Comment: the browser has its own caching... so why should you worry about it?

Comment: I want to cache the images locally (i.e. on my server) to reduce load times and prevent broken images in case Flickr is down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using django for your web application, try https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

There is no such caching implemented in the Python Flickr API library. It's also not always allowed to do such a thing, as you'd be copying images from the Flickr servers, and distributing them from your own website. If an image is marked "all rights reserved", you don't have the right to do that.

Comment: These are images that my own organization uploads, so we do have the right to redistribute. The ownership part is important for others who land on this thread looking for a solution though.